# How do I do damage with spawned particles with MCreator?

Tags: minecraft-modding

I would like to create a sword that summons particles that do damage (like the katanas of the demon slayer mod) could someone help me? I've been trying for days.

Comment: IIRC particles are entirely cosmetic by definition. So you either have some entities that are not particles and do damage, or you do damage and make particles (which don't do damage but you already did the damage)

Comment: then I have two questions:
1) is it possible to create an invisible entity?
2) can I make the attack zone bigger than 1x1?

Comment: yes for both, probably